# How to read multiple sensors, store into an array, sort and then do something with the results—Arduino

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, led, batteries, digital-logic

I have a small project that I could use help understanding how best to move forward.

I have a set of 8 batteries of different voltages and age.

I’d like to read the voltages of all, assign an identifier to each battery , store those voltages in an array (I assume), then sort the array from the highest voltage to the lowest, pick the top 4 highest voltage batteries, and then “do something” (like light a led next to each of those 4 batteries indicating the top 4 highest voltages).

Although I’m quite a Arduino newbie, I do know how to read the battery voltages. The rest I have a vague idea but really stumbling with how to sort and then do something with the curated sorted list.

Thanks for any help or guidance!

Comment: This might be a better fit for the Arduino stackexchange.

Comment: I assume you mean you know how to read the battery voltages *in place*, because you talk of lighting an LED next to each.

Comment: @TimWescott thanks for the reply. Yes, I believe I know how to test in place. The led indicator would be driven from another pin and located next to the battery.

Answer (score 0):

So, your question about how to sort this and do something with it is a general programming question, not specifically an Arduino question.

There's many ways to skin this cat.  The way *I'd* do it would be to define a structure with everything about the battery that I wanted to know -- let's assume it's just the voltage and physical position:

```
struct BatteryDescriptor {
  float voltage;
  unsigned int position;
};
```

I would make an array of that structure, one per battery.  Then I'd sort that array on voltage.  There are a **lot** of ways to do this.  If you have a full C library available you can use qsort.  I'm assuming you don't have the STL library available.  Finally, you can roll your own.

There are a LOT of sorting algorithms out there.  Because you're only sorting eight things, and you're a beginner, I recommend a bubble sort.  Google it.  Further, I recommend that you do the sorting in place (as opposed to making an array of pointers to your array of descriptors, or making your descriptors into a linked list).

When you're done, you should have the four highest-voltage batteries at the beginning or end of your list.  You can step through that with a for loop and turn on your LEDs.